# Webscraping with selenium, beautiful soup, python - trouble finding specific text

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I am quite new to python and webscraping and I am trying to pull the following text ($1.74), and all the other relevant odds on the page from a website:

[HMTL text that I am trying to pull](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WHFfz.png)

For similar situations previously I have been successful by using a for loop inside another for loop, but on those occasions I was searching by 'class'. I cannot search by class here as there are a lot of other 'td's that have the same class type, and not the odds that I want. Here I would like to (and I am not sure if it is possible) search via 'data-bettype'. The reason I am trying to search via that, and not 'data compid data-bettype', is that when I print out the full HTML in python, it looks like so:

[HMTL printed to Python](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iLtJp.png)

The relevant part of my code here is:

```
soup_playup = BeautifulSoup(source_playup, 'lxml')

#print(soup_playup.prettify())

for odds_a in soup_playup.find_all('td',{'data-bettype','Awin'}):
    for odds in odds_a.find_all('div'):
        print(odds.text)
```

I am not receiving any errors when I run this code, but it seems as though it just will not find the text.

Comment: If I understand correct, the output that you have pasted was when you have tried to find using the attribute 'data-compid data-bettype'. But from the previous screenshot, it appears to be two different attributes inside the td tag. So, giving only the 'data-bettype' should work fine in getting the value if it is a unique attribute. Let me know if I am missing anything.

Comment: Sorry that it wasn't clear. The output that I pasted is when I run a print function on the soup_playup. I posted this to show that what is showing up in python is different from what is showing up when I 'inspect' on the browser.

Comment: The class attribute value in your output and given HTML looks different, the code might be finding a different td tag. So can you check if there are any duplicate td tag with different value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct format for looking up attributes is a dictionary of key-value pairs like so:

```
soup_playup.find_all('td',attrs={'data-bettype':'Awin'})
```